# AdonisJs 4.1: how to create a start script that migrates the db and start the server?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, adonis.js

I have a dockerized AdonisJs App that I'm trying to deploy on ECS (AWS). I managed to deploy the image but now I don't know how to run migrations when I deploy.

By following a Udemy course I saw that somebody had to do the same stuff, but with laravel. In the Dockerfile instead of running `CMD ['artisan','serve']` he created a start.sh script where he starts the app, put it in the background, runs the migrations, and then put the app back in the background. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# turn on bash's job control
set -m

# Start the primary process and put it in the background
php-fpm &

# Start the helper process
php artisan migrate

# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
# and leave it there
fg %1
```

I tried to do the same thing with Adonis, this is my script (one of many versions):

```
#!/bin/sh

# turn on bash's job control
set -m

# Start the primary process and put it in the background
adonis serve &

# Start the helper process
adonis migration:run

# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
# and leave it there
fg %1
```

But I always get errors. For example:

1. The server starts but then the migrations do not run because adonis cannot connect to the database. I don't know how to debug it, since if I just start the app normally Adonis can perfectly connect to the database.
2. (I tried this only locally) The server starts, the migrations run but then the server process doesn't come in foreground so the application is not really started (`curl localhost` it gives me `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`) and I cannot either stop the server with ctrl+c, I have to find the docker container and stop the container.
   This is what the console shows me:

```
 SERVER STARTED 

info: serving app on http://0.0.0.0:80
Nothing to migrate
```

Could you please help me create a script that does this?

EDIT1: I noticed that even if I create a script with only "adonis serve" it still doesn't work, so maybe that it's just not the right way to start the server trough a script?

Comment: Run migrations : `node ace migration:run --force` & start server : `node server.js`

Comment: Tried it, but the migration doesn't exit/finish.

Comment: I noticed that even if I create a script with only "adonis serve" it still doesn't work, so maybe that it's just not the right way to start the server trough a script?

Comment: migration doesn't exit/finish -> check if database is up and accessible. check your migrations files

Comment: Run server : `node server.js`

Comment: Database connection is fine (I found a related issue: https://github.com/adonisjs/core/issues/1027 but the solution is not written).
When I run ```node server.js``` it says that the server started, but I can't access it and can't even stop it with CTRL-C.

Comment: After a day of debugging I found out that the problem was with how I was starting ```adonis-scheduler``` package. I was starting it from he kernel.js file, now instead I'm starting it from server.js file the migration terminate and I can start adonis with ```adonis serve``` (don't know why but ```node server.js``` doesn't work). Is node server.js recommended over adonis serve? If yes why? By the way thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. You cannot use `adonis serve` because you cannot install package globaly in your hosting provider. Don't know why but node server.js doesn't work -> why? any logs?

Comment: In production I use PM2 : `pm2 start server.js`

Comment: Do you use it inside docker?

Comment: Do you use it inside docker? -> no

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I needed to solve was the migration command that wasn't terminating. The cause was how I was starting the `adonis-scheduler` package. I was starting it from the start/kernel.js file. Now instead I created a `scheduler.js` (inside start) with:

```
'use strict'

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run Scheduler
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Run the scheduler on boot of the web sever.
|
*/
const Scheduler = use('Adonis/Addons/Scheduler')
Scheduler.run()
```

And added this in server.js:

```
new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
  .appRoot(__dirname)
  .preLoad('start/scheduler') //code added
  .fireHttpServer()
  .catch(console.error)
```

By doing this my migration always terminates.

The second problem I faced was that "#!/bin/bash" wasn't supported, so I needed to change the script in a "#!/bin/sh" format. Unfortunately this format doesn't support putting job in background and move them in foreground later, so I just run the migrations and then start the server. This is the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start the helper process
adonis key:generate
adonis migration:run --force

# Start the primary process
adonis serve
```